# How to make this in Flutter i am new in flutter so if anyone knows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-design

[image]

I want one row with this one big image on left and two images on right with one up and the second down.
thanks in advance if Someone can help!!

Answer (score 1):

The key insight is to break the layout into nested rows and/or columns. Check out this example,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: getContainer(Colors.green),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: getContainer(Colors.yellow),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: getContainer(Colors.red),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget getContainer(MaterialColor color) =>
    Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is contained in one row, the first column will be larger than the second one with the widget Expanded flex :1.  In the second column, there's a column widget with that you'll have two rows for your image.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: Image.asset('your large image'),
              ),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('your second image'),
                  Image.asset('your third image'),
                ],
              ),
              flex: 0,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**solved**
[image]

**here is the example **

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BagScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BagScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          // color: Colors.red,
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/bgimage.PNG",
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  width: 250.0,
                  // height: 350.0,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10.0,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/upsm.PNG"),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/upsm.PNG"),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```